# During startup program exited normally. gdb doesn't break at breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I'm receiving this gdb error on any code I try to debug any program with gdb. Here's the simplest process that reproduces the error

1. Create a `main.cpp` file with this content:

```c
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

2. Run `g++ -g main.cpp`
3. Run `gdb a.out`
4. Inside gdb set a break point at line 2 with `break 2`
5. In gdb run the program with `run`

Output:

```
Starting program: /tmp/test/a.out 
During startup program exited normally.
```

This is all done with gdb on the command line. I've tried using g++ and gcc with the same result. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

- gdb version = 9.2
- g++ version = 9.3.0

EDIT: I figured out what is causing the issue, but not how to fix it. The issue seems to be something related to my `SHELL` variable. I'm currently using [xonsh](https://xon.sh/) as my shell but when I set my `SHELL` environment variable back to `/bin/bash` everything works as expected. Is there anything I can do to fix this while using xonsh? Should I report this to xonsh, gdb, both or neither?

Comment: There is no current source file before run, break 2 does not work. You should get a warning.

Comment: @S.M. Don't think that's true. It's common to set such breakpoints after loading the binary but before running it. Well, at least it works on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm currently using xonsh as my shell but when I set my SHELL environment variable back to /bin/bash everything works as expected. Is there anything I can do to fix this while using xonsh? Should I report this to xonsh, gdb, both or neither?

This might be your `xonsh` startup problem, or it might be `xonsh` problem, or it could be that `xonsh` doesn't do what GDB expects it to do.

Normally, GDB `fork`s / `exec`s `$SHELL -c "/path/to/your/exe $args"` and expects the `$SHELL` to `exec` your program (this is done so shell redirection still works under GDB).

Only *after* that `exec` will GDB start setting breakpoints, etc.

If you have some `xonsh` init-file, which e.g. causes `xonsh` to `exec` something else, things could go bad. So I suggest trying to remove any such `~/.xonshrc` or whatever it's called file, and seeing whether that fixes the problem.

If it doesn't, it could be that `xonsh` e.g. `fork`s and `exec`s your binary in a child (grandchild of GDB) instead of doing it directly, or it could be that `xonsh` doesn't understand the `-c ...` syntax.

---

If you don't care about redirection, you could also ask GDB to not use `$SHELL` at all: `set startup-with-shell off`. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#Starting).