# GDB not breaking on main

Tags: c++, gdb

I am having a very weird issue debugging with gdb. I have reduced it to the following minimal example.

Create `test.cc`, with the contents:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "this is ridiculous" << std::endl;
}
```

and compile it using `g++`: `g++ test.cc -g -Og -o out`
`./out` works as expected, but `gdb ./out` behaves weird:

```
~ gdb ./out
Reading symbols from ./out...
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11df: file test.cc, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/c/tmp/s/out
this is ridiculous
During startup program exited normally.
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Things I have checked:

### Symbols are there:

```
~ objdump -x out | grep main
000000000000120c l     F .text  000000000000001c              _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
00000000000011df g     F .text  000000000000002d              main
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34
```

### The assembly output

[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/1Jrg6F7J)

### Multiple Machines

Occurs on:

- `ubuntu 22.04 with g++ 11.4.0`
- `arch with clang 17`
- `arch with g++ 13.2.1`

### GDB parses symbols

```
~ gdb ./out
(gdb) info functions
All defined functions:

File test.cc:
3:  int main();
    static void _GLOBAL__sub_I_main();
    static void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int);

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000001000  _init
0x0000000000001070  __cxa_finalize@plt
0x0000000000001080  std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@plt
0x0000000000001090  __cxa_atexit@plt
0x00000000000010a0  std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)@plt
0x00000000000010b0  std::ios_base::Init::Init()@plt
0x00000000000010c0  _start
0x00000000000010f0  deregister_tm_clones
0x0000000000001120  register_tm_clones
0x0000000000001160  __do_global_dtors_aux
0x00000000000011a0  frame_dummy
0x0000000000001228  _fini
```

### Edit: More Investigation

After continued investigation, I've noted the following:

1. plain `c` programs also exhibit this behavior.
2. the `starti` gdb command does not work, behaving like `run`
3. when running in a debian docker container, everything works correctly

Point 3, to me, implies it is a bug in gdb, but that makes no sense, as:

- it occurs on two different machines with two different versions of gdb (12.1 and 13.2).
- gdb is installed from the main ubuntu/arch repos. I imagine that is one of the best-tested pieces of software out there

Are there more tests I can run to nail down the issue?

Comment: Did you try dropping the `-O` option entirely and compiling without it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, still fails

Comment: why not use CPPFLAGS and make?  How does that even compile when you don't return a value from main?

Comment: @UpAndAdam this originally occured using the meson build system. I do not understand the suggestion of `make`, as it is just calling `g++` like I do. Adding `return 0;` at the end does not change the behavior

Comment: @UpAndAdam Please see [basic.start.main#5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5): `"If control flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to a return with operand 0"`.

Comment: @G.M. if you are going to throw a language lawyer quote at me, use something that doesnt say 'draft' from website I've never heard of.  the draft even says " Note: this is an early draft. It's known to be incomplet and incorrekt, and it has lots of bad formatting."
OP: I get it you were simplifying out meson for us and showing us the actual commands executed Very fair point.

Comment: @G.M. that said i found other posts that indicate you are correct. that is news to me as I've always gotten errors/warnings when it has been omitted.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, what happens if you use the version of GDB that comes with it (9.2)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I mistakenly indicated 20.04, I meant 22.04. Currently getting an old version of gdb to test with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273682/during-startup-program-exited-normally-gdb-doesnt-break-at-breakpoints) contains the answer -- in short: gdb uses the `shell` environment variable to determine how to spawn the program at start. I am using a non-posix shell, which broke everything.